# Menu items -buttons- and how to make them interact in a C#/MySql POS

Tags: c#, mysql, event-handling, imagebutton

Hoping you all are having an excellent week so far.

I've been developing a POS application on CSharp/MySql, and right now I'm having a big confusion on how to manage button events (ie. what I've thought so far is that if the waiter clicks on a certain product after clicking on a certain table number, then this would generate an insert to the database for later consult, with a flag that will depict that the check is open)...

Raw coding so far (I still need to adjust the button names and functions, but the first button click case describes the idea I'm trying to implement):

```
    String product = string.Empty;
    String price = string.Empty;
    Double total = 0.0;

    string operand1 = string.Empty;
    string operand2 = string.Empty;
    string result;
    char operation; 

    public LaCarta()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayTime();
    }

    private void LaCarta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        CoronaClara.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CoronaLight.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CoronaObscura.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        Refresco.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaranjadaGde.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaranjadaCh.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        LimonadaGde.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        LimonadaCh.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        HorchataGde.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        HorchataCh.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        AguaDePepinoGde.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaipeCorazon.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaipeDiamante.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaipeEspada.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NaipeTrebol.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        AguaDePepinoCh.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CervezaPacifico.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CervezaLeon.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CervezaVictoria.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        NegraModelo.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CubetaDe20Pz.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CubetaDe10Pz.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        CaguamaCorona.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        JarraDeCheve.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        LitroDeCheve.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        MiniTarro.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        MicheladaGde.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    }

    private void displayTime()
    {
        label21.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        label22.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char open = 'Y';
        int table = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;username=root;password=***");

        //Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
        try
        {

            string query = "SELECT * FROM check where table_id = '" + table + "' and open = '" + open + "'";   
           // dataGridView1.DataSource = getData(query);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading table");
        }
        finally {
            mcon.Close();
        }
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;username=root;password=***");
            mcon.Open();

            switch (btn.Name)
            {
                case "CoronaClara":
                    product = "CoronaClara";
                    LaCuenta.Items.Add(product);

                    string select = "SELECT price FROM products where prodnom = '" + product + "';";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(select, mcon);
                    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    precio = Convert.ToString(result);

                    //precio = Convert.ToDouble(result);
                    LaCuenta.Items.Add(product + " " + "$" + price);

                    txtInput.Text += price;


                    break;

                case "btnTwo":
                    //txtInput.Text += "2";
                    break;
                case "btnThree":
                    //txtInput.Text += "3";
                    break;
                case "btnFour":
                    //txtInput.Text += "4";
                    break;
                case "btnFive":
                    //txtInput.Text += "5";
                    break;
                case "btnSix":
                    //txtInput.Text += "6";
                    break;
                case "btnSeven":
                    //txtInput.Text += "7";
                    break;
                case "btnEight":
                    //txtInput.Text += "8";
                    break;
                case "btnNine":
                    //txtInput.Text += "9";
                    break;
                case "btnZero":
                    //txtInput.Text += "0";
                    break;
                case "btnDot":
                    //if (!txtInput.Text.Contains("."))
                    //    txtInput.Text += ".";
                    break;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry for the inconvenience, Unexpected error occured. Details: " +
                ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void bttn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text = operand1;
        operation = '*';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void bttn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '*';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void bttn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '*';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void bttn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '*';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand2 = txtInput.Text;

        double opr1, opr2;
        double.TryParse(operand1, out opr1);
        double.TryParse(operand2, out opr2);

        result = (opr1 * opr2).ToString();
        txtInput.Text = result.ToString();
    } 
 }
```

And this would be basically the elements that I want to interact with each other: the imagebuttons, the listbox, the multiplicators, the gridview from where you'll be able to select a number of table or client name, and the total amount.

[image: Menu items view]

**So my questions are:**

- Do you consider I'm going on the right way?
- How can I make these button click events interact with each other?

**Thank you very much for your time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many flaws in your code! First of all try to regroup the DB connection query in a single utility function. This will reduce code redundancy and believe me will greatly simplify your life. Second, i am sure a product is not just a string. It contains a name, a price, etc... Create a class product and add all the details, this will allow you to obtain info. much more easily. Lastly, in design mode in property panel there is the event part, click it and for each button set the Click event to btn_Click.

If i understood well, for your second question, creating a class for products will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was very helpful for me to understand the program logic better.

Comment: please flag as answered if it really helps, btw i developed a simillar app